# Can I compare entries of a same table based on their different dates?

Tags: sql-server, datetime, stored-procedures, comparison, procedure

I am creating a procedure that receives two dates as parameters.

The procedure works on a table that has the following columns (I'd put a picture of the actual table but I don't have enough reputation yet):

**date displayName label capacity**

The data contained in the table have been collected over a few years and from one day the displayName columns refer the the name of a Vmware.  Thus, it is possible that the start date only has 3 entries and that the end date has 5 (reflecting that Vmwares were created in between).  What I would like to do it as follow.  Given a start and an end date, I would like to be able to select only the displayName (along with their label and capacity) that have been created (or added if you will) between the two dates.  What I have is

```
CREATE PROCEDURE afficherCreationLuns @start Date, @end Date
AS
BEGIN
SELECT dateCollecte, DisplayName, label, capacity
FROM Vsp
WHERE dateCollecte = @end AND displayName NOT IN (SELECT displayName
                                                    FROM Vsp
                                                    WHERE dateCollecte = @start)
END
```

This only works if the start date is the exact one were the Vmware were created (and thus the displayName added to the entries).  If you pick a date before that nothing is appears.

I have also tried 
    WHERE dateCollecte >= @start AND dateCollecte < @end

But this never worked no matter the chosen dates.

I also tried defining the dates like this

```
@start Date = '2014-05-01', @end = '2014-05-02'
```

but it doesn't change anything.

Now I am not sure if it can be done, but I would also like the following:

1. to show in the date column of the table not the end date (like my code does there) but the date on which the Vmware were created (and thus the entries added)
2. to show the displayName that has been created even if it has been destroyed.  i.e. if the 10th I have 3 entries, that a Vmware is created the 12th (I now have 4 entries for the this date) and destroyed the 13th, I would like for it to appear if the selected dates are start = 10th and end = 14.

Thanks for the help guys!

P.S.  Here is the structure of the table if it helps:

```
----------------
Columns for: Vsp
----------------
----------DEV_TechnoWin  dbo            Vsp            id             4              int identity   10             4              0              10             0              4              1              NO             56
----------DEV_TechnoWin  dbo            Vsp            dateCollecte   -9             date           10             20             1              -9             2              YES            0
----------DEV_TechnoWin  dbo            Vsp            displayName    -9             nvarchar       250            500            1              -9             500            3              YES            39
----------DEV_TechnoWin  dbo            Vsp            capacityInKB   6              float          15             8              10             1              6              4              YES            109
----------DEV_TechnoWin  dbo            Vsp            consumedCapacityInKB6              float          15             8              10             1              6              5              YES            109
----------DEV_TechnoWin  dbo            Vsp            dpPoolId       4              int            10             4              0              10             1              4              6              YES            38
----------DEV_TechnoWin  dbo            Vsp            label          -9             nvarchar       250            500            1              -9             500            7              YES            39
----------DEV_TechnoWin  dbo            Vsp            tieringPolicy  4              int            10             4              0              10             1              4              8              YES            38
----------DEV_TechnoWin  dbo            Vsp            dpTier0ConsumedCapacityInKB6              float          15             8              10             1              6              9              YES            109
----------DEV_TechnoWin  dbo            Vsp            dpTier1ConsumedCapacityInKB6              float          15             8              10             1              6              10             YES            109
----------DEV_TechnoWin  dbo            Vsp            dpTier2ConsumedCapacityInKB6              float          15             8              10             1              6              11             YES            109
----------DEV_TechnoWin  dbo            Vsp            dateImport     -9             date           10             20             1              -9             12             YES            0
```

Comment: Can you add some example of the data in you system? The `WHERE dateCollecte >= @start AND dateCollecte < @end` should have work

Answer (score 0):

try using [BETWEEN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms187922.aspx) in your case

```
CREATE PROCEDURE afficherCreationLuns (@start Date, @end Date)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT dateCollecte, DisplayName, label, capacity
FROM Vsp
WHERE dateCollecte BETWEEN @end AND @start
END
```

BY msdn

> The query retrieves the expected rows because the date values in the
>   query and the datetime values stored in the RateChangeDate column have
>   been specified without the time part of the date. When the time part
>   is unspecified, it defaults to 12:00 A.M. Note that a row that
>   contains a time part that is after 12:00 A.M. on 2002-01-05 would not
>   be returned by this query because it falls outside the range.

Comment: I'm not sure that's the problem, like I said I managed to make something appear with the first code.

Comment: can you make fiddle of it so i can give you correct answer

Comment: I edited the answer but ya I've tried defining the dates in various ways never seemed to make a difference.  If you have a particular way of defining them you want me to try just say!

Comment: default sql server format is YYYY-MM-DD try this execute your store p and see what output comes, can you show your table entries of date

Comment: doesn't work either.  And since I can't attach pictures (I don't have enough reputations for that) I can't really show my table

Comment: generate script of your table schema and paste here

Comment: I added it in the question though it's quite hard to read sorry about that

Comment: is your date stored as 10, 20 etc in your dataCollecte column?

Comment: it's stored as 2014-06-26

Comment: can you make fiddle of it nothing is clear with table schema you posted

Comment: I'm sorry English isn't my first language, what do you mean make fiddle of it?

Comment: I don't think that's any good, I have way to much values in my table to insert them in there.  Anyway that's the table http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2c6ab